# Why can't I insert data into mysql server?

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 scripts that log things on my website to a mysql database. They both use the same database on the same server, with the only difference being the table. The code i am using to insert values looks like this:

```
INSERT INTO table(full_name, email_address, phone_number, message, ip_address, agent)
VALUES ('$fn', '$email', '$telephone', '$comments', '$ip', '$agent')
```

Can anyone tell me why one script will work and the other will not?

Comment: Little Bobby Tables would like a word with you.

Comment: Do you get an error? If yes, which one?

Comment: Is the TABLE really named `table`? That word (`table`) is [reserved in SQL](http://developer.mimer.com/validator/sql-reserved-words.tml) and must be escaped... but better, *just use a better table name* ... **and placeholders**. (As an injection attack or just silly unexpected data, e.g. $comment contains `silly'php`, **will break you programs** while *being hard to detect* -- Oops!)

Comment: is that enclosed in double or single quotes

Comment: What does "will not work" mean?

Comment: Ok. The table is not really named table, it is in double quotes, and "will not work" means that when i try to run the script, i get an error and no data is inserted into the table. Here is the error: `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'log(tm, ref, agent, ip, page) VALUES ([tm], [ref], [agent] ' at line 1`

Comment: You will get much better help if you post the actual code you are using.  Substituting `table` for the table name can throw us off the actual error.

Comment: sorry about that. I'll remember to leave the code as it is from now on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error nearly always occurs exactly where the `'` starts in the error message. Looks like you're inserting into a table called `log` and although I didn't think it's a reserved MySQL keyword, you might try quoting the table name with backquotes and putting a space before the opening parenthesis:

```
INSERT INTO `log` (tm, ref, agent, ip, page) VALUES (....);
```

**UPDATE** `LOG()` isn't a keyword, but it is a MySQL numeric function.  And since you're using it right beside parentheses, MySQL is likely interpreting this as a faulty function call.  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-functions.html

Comment: This worked. Thank you Michael. The part about this that confuses me is the fact that I was using this same script exactly as it is on a different web server and it worked perfectly. Are there any differences between MySQL on Windows and MySQL on Linux that might have caused the problem?

Comment: @cheeseisedible Not sure. There are differences in default case-sensitivity between them (Win is not sensitive) but I don't know that would affect a function name.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `mysql_error()` to check for errors.

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO table(
         full_name, email_address, phone_number, message, ip_address, agent) 
         VALUES ('$fn', '$email', '$telephone', '$comments', '$ip', '$agent')")
         or die(mysql_error());
```